# C1 flexgrid merge cell when dynamically present data are same

Tags: vb.net, c1flexgrid

I am using C1 flexgrid in vb.net for windows form project
At my form I want to merge rows of column when data are same that I dynamically filled from Database.
How can I merge row of column in c1 flex grid

Answer (score 2):

[Please refer this ComponentOne HelpCentral article](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/#mergingcells.html)

The C1FlexGrid control allows you to merge cells, making them span multiple rows or columns. This capability can be used to enhance the appearance and clarity of the data displayed on the grid. The effect of these settings is similar to the HTML  and  tags.

To enable cell merging, you must do two things:

1. Set the grid's AllowMerging property to a value other than None. (The effect of each setting is explained in the reference section.)
2. If you want to merge columns, set the AllowMerging property to True for each column that you would like to merge. If you want to merge rows, set the AllowMerging property to True for each row that you would like to merge.

Merging will occur if adjacent cells contain the same non-empty string. There is no method to force a pair of cells to merge. The merging is done automatically based on the cell contents. This makes it easy to provide merged views of sorted data, where values in adjacent rows present repeated data.

Cell merging works the same way when the grid is bound to a data source.

The code below shows an example for a grid bound to a data source at design time.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim i As Integer
    _flex.AllowMerging = C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.AllowMergingEnum.RestrictCols
    For i As Integer = _flex.Cols.Fixed To _flex.Cols.Count - 1
        _flex.Cols(i).AllowMerging = True
    Next
End Sub
```